# Python pool spawining pools

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I have a function which uses `multiprocessing.Pool` to process all the data in **one** dataset in parallel.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
...
def func():
    ...
    p = Pool(processes=N)
    p.map(func, params)
    ...
```

However, I now want to run this for `M` different datasets in parallel. So I have written another script on top of my existing one above. I tried using `Pool` again to create `M` processes (each of which would spawn a `Pool` of `N` processes). However, I get an error about a daemon not be able to spawn children (which sounds very rock 'n' roll). So I do some reading and switch out `Pool` for the little know `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool`. So it looks like

```
p = ThreadPool(processes=M)
p.starmap(func, args)
```

However, when I run this, I see that `ThreadPool` is only processing one dataset at a time. So what should I be using to be able to have a script which spawns `M` children, each of which spawn `N` children and does it all in parallel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the example with `Manager.Queue()`. (not Monitor as I wrote in comments, my bad).  It is really a very simple program if you take out all the keyboard interrupt exception handling trying to make it shut down nicely, which it still doesn't do. Now you have an outer pool of processes, that in turn spawn a Pool to execute tasks. A queue is used to feed tasks to outer pool workers, which in turn feed them to workers. They are in infinite loop waiting for something to arrive in the queue.

You can of course add control messages there as well (for example if an outer pool worker receives the word "exit", it will shut down its pool and exit nicely) if you want to manage the outer pool workers and tell them do different things.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, Process
from time import sleep
from random import randint
from multiprocessing import Manager
import sys


alist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]


def worker(a):
    try:
        print a
        sleep(randint(0, 2))
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass


def outer_pool(iq, n):
    _ip = Pool(processes=7)
    try:
        while True:
            y = iq.get()
            _param = []
            for _ny in alist:
                _param.append("%d - %d - %d" % (n, _ny, y))
            _ip.map(worker, _param)

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        try:
            _ip.terminate()
        except:
            pass


c_queue = Manager().Queue()

o_processes = []
for t in alist:
    p = Process(target=outer_pool, args=(c_queue, t))
    p.start()
    o_processes.append(p)

try:
    while True:
        a = randint(42,100)
        c_queue.put(a)
except KeyboardInterrupt:

    for _p in o_processes:
        try:
            _p.terminate()
        except:
            pass
    sys.exit(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just write out the outer Pool and use Process instead.  Threads are notoriously bad performers in Python because of GIL.

This doesn't really do anything but gives the idea:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, Process
from time import sleep
from random import randint

list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

def worker(a):
    print a
    sleep(randint(0,2))


def f1(a):
    _p = Pool(processes=7)
    _p.map(worker, list)
    _p.close()
    _p.join()


def f2():
    processes = []
    for _i in list:
        p = Process(target=f1, args=(_i,))
        p.start()
        processes.append(p)
    for _q in processes:
        q.join()

f2()
```

It will launch seven Processes, which in turn launch a pool each, and f2 waits for all of them to finish.

Comment: I'm really frustrated now as I tried this as my very first attempt but ran into issues with my inner pool only spawning 1 worker. I've implemented as you've laid out and it works perfectly. Thanks! Not sure what I did incorrectly before.

Comment: If you need "Pool" like behaviour for the outer thing as well, you can of course create processes and communicate with them using `Monitor.Queue()`, and feed them tasks they then process. It might just add complexity, though, but doable if your outer loop processes need to be able to run another task as soon as they complete the one they are processing.

Comment: That sounds much more like what I need

Comment: Could I trouble you for an example of that?

Comment: Sure, but it will have to wait until tomorrow. I'll try to remember it in the morning.